# The formula of probability

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, normal-distribution

I have a very basic question about probability and the formula for calculating the probability of an event
Image an event (like A) we're using the ratio n(A)/n(S) to calculate the probability of this event . Is there a proof for this formula or is it just a definition?? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, it depends.  If you assume that each element in $S$ is equally probable, then it follows (since each element must then have probability $\frac 1{n(S)}$ and there are $n(A)$ elements which comprise $A$).  But you could could also just say that this is the definition of uniform probability.

Comment: What is "event Image"? What is S?

Comment: @lulu thanks for your kindness 

Comment: @user it's just an example , I mean consider an event like (A) .

Comment: This explains neither the meaning of the "event Image" nor that of $S $.